# Accessing Data of a ComboBox with an ArrayCollection dataProvider

Tags: apache-flex

```
[Bindable]
public var groupsList:ArrayCollection;

public function groupListRH(event:ResultEvent):void
{ 
     groupsList=event.result as ArrayCollection;       
}

<mx:ComboBox dataProvider="{groupsList}" 
             labelField="groupName"
             id="grpLst"  width="150"
             prompt="Select one group "                                   
             close="selectedItem=ComboBox(event.target).selectedIndex"               
             focusIn="init();" /> 

<mx:LinkButton label="New Group" id="creatgrp" click="addNewGroup();"/>
```

Here am getting array of groups(groupName,GroupID each row ) from a RemoteObject and displaying in a ComboBox. I am selecting the groups with selectedIndex as 0,1,2,3, but I want my groupIDs of correspoding groupnames,which am bringing to client side.

How can I get actual the groupId of the selected group?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get it like so:

```
grpLst.selectedItem.GroupID;
```

**EDIT**

Or from within an `mx.events.ListEvent.CHANGE` handler attached to the `ComboBox`:

```
event.target.selectedItem.GroupID
```

**EDIT**

Ah, the code formatting has been updated and its easier to read.  I see you are using the close event, and setting a variable called `selectedItem` to the `selectedIndex` property of the `ComboBox`.  You could just change it so that the variable `selectedItem` actually references the `selectedItem` propterty of the `ComboBox` like so:

```
selectedItem=(event.target as ComboBox).selectedIndex;
// Then get the GroupID from the selectedItem
selectedGroupID = selectedItem.GroupID
```

Or just use the index to get the data from the `dataProvider`:

```
selectedIndex=(event.target as ComboBox).selectedIndex;
// Then get the GroupID from the dataProvider
selectedGroupID = groupList[selectedIndex]['GroupID']
```

Comment: public function groupListRH(event:ResultEvent):void
{ groupsList=event.result as ArrayCollection;}
 public function show(event):void
{selectedItem=(event.target as ComboBox).selectedIndex;
Alert.show(selectedItem.toString().groupId);}
<mx:ComboBox dataProvider="{groupsList}" labelField="groupName"
id="grpLst"width="150"  prompt="Select One Group" change="show(event);" focusIn="init();" />    

am not getting like this ...how can i get groupId(exact id which am getting into arraycollection thru remoteobject) of selected GroupName...??

Comment: Append an edit to your question with that code, or create a new question.  I'm not a compiler so I can only parse code when it's formatted visually. ;-)